# Invalid AES key length: 64 bytes

Tags: java, encryption, groovy, openssl, aes

I am trying to encode using a static key say as an example: "B3FFCA612CD0C3D9050A4DE3588E2830F26BEF6D7E1CEC77DD2F22FAFC038D33" in AES and ECB mode. when i try this with openssl, I successfully get a result with no issues but when I code it in groovy or java:

**Invalid AES key length: 64 bytes**

when I researched this, the issue occurs because the key length can be 32 bytes at most, now I am confused because the API i am sending these encrpions to, completely works with the 64 byte key i am sending but fails with the 32 byte one. openssl encodes this too with the 64 byte key I provide as below:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -e -in infile.txt -a -A -K B3FFCA612CD0C3D9050A4DE3588E2830F26BEF6D7E1CEC77DD2F22FAFC038D33 -iv 0 -p
```

I want to be able to do the same but in groovy/java.

I am not sure what I am missing, I would really apprecaite your help on this please!

here is my code:

```
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;



class AESCrypt {


// encrypt
def encrypt (def plainText, def secret) {

def cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")


// converty string secret to SecretKeySpec
byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret);
SecretKeySpec key= new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey , 0, decodedKey.length, 
"AES");


cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)

return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8")).encodeBase64().toString()  

}

}

//Main
for( int i = 0; i < dataContext.getDataCount(); i++ ) {
  InputStream is = dataContext.getStream(i);
  Properties props = dataContext.getProperties(i);

def c = new AESCrypt()

def secret = 
"B3FFCA612CD0C3D9050A4DE3588E2830F26BEF6D7E1CEC77DD2F22FAFC038D33"

//get plaintext of payload
Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
String plainPayload = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";

//encrypt plaintext of payload
def encryptedPayload = c.encrypt(plainPayload, secret)

println encryptedPayload + "\n"



}
```

Comment: As an aside, you are using ECB encryption, which is a very poor form of encryption. Please consider using CBC, at least.

Comment: Look up the static method `parseHexBinary()` of the [DatatypeConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) class.

Comment: @vcsjones thanks for the comment. unfortunately, I am using an API fot an application which requires this encryption. I have no access to that application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> openssl encodes this too with the 64 byte key I provide as below.

It's not a 64-byte key. It's a 32-byte key that's been [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) encoded, which results in 64 letters.

You are trying to base64 decode your secret, which is not the same as hexadecimal.

I'm not a Java or Groovy expert, but may be able to use `decodeHex()` on your string to hex decode it instead of base64 decode it.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot. Yes it is Hex encoded and need to use:
Hex.decodeHex

Comment: @Nat how did you apply it?